# Decide whether the argument is valid and the form.

Tags: logic

If you see a lion, you will walk away.
If you walk away, it won't eat you.

---

If you see a lion, then it won't eat you.

My answer said: The argument is valid by modus ponens. Why am I wrong?

Comment: Mostly that the lion is faster than you are.

Comment: You haven't explained why you think you were wrong in the first place. There must be some context that made you think you were wrong; that same context is needed to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

[Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) tells you that $P\to Q, P\vdash Q$ is a valid argument.

The argument in the question doesn't look like this at all, nor is it a particular case of a possible generalized version of the above.

Your argument is of the form $P\to Q, Q\to R\vdash P\to R$ and it is valid by the [hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism) (or reasoning by transivity) inference rule.

Comment: @ git gud is that the same as disjunctive syllogism?

Comment: @MethodManX No. The disjunctive syllogysm says that $P\lor Q, \neg P\vdash Q$ is a valid argument.

Comment: @ Git Gud: The choices that I have to choose from are: Disjunctive syllogism, modus tollens, fallacy of the inverse, modus ponens, reasoning transtivity, and fallacy of the converse. 

there's no hypotheical syllogism unless there's another word for it?

Comment: @MethodManX Hypothetical syllogism is reasoning by transivity.